# How to get https links after redirecting from KeyCloak

Tags: spring, spring-boot, https, keycloak

We have a spring boot application and set up keycloak long time ago.
Everything was working like it has to until we saw that some links after redirecting are in http and not https:

This is what I already tried to fix the problem:

1)

Added the following properties:

```
server.use-forward-headers=true
server.tomcat.internal-proxies=.*
server.tomcat.remote-ip-header=x-forwarded-for
server.tomcat.protocol-header=x-forwarded-proto
```

When I added those somehow the behaviour changed and keycloak "generated" an URI with port 0 added to the (external) link. This caused a 403 error.

To fix that issue I had to add the following line to my keycloak config:

2)

```
"confidential-port": 443
```

That successfully removed the port 0 from my link and redirected me but I still got a 403 error.

This is what I see in the logs:

```
ERROR [bootstrap,,,] 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : Adapter requires SSL. Request: http://example.be/REST/location/sso/login?state=df826bc4-86c1-4af5-b5fb-51f03107c18b&session_state=9ba8e48a-9d81-407f-9cf4-d50308793818&code=ea14f45f-775a-4a28-b94b-8856b7880890.9ba8e48a-9d81-407f-9cf4-d50308793818.915a1b76-9f38-48fe-bed6-7404bd5caf21
```

I tried a lot this time too but nothing gave me results.

Remark that in the logs we see http and not https.
In my browser I go to https in the navigation bar.

EDIT:

I debugged into the code and found the following:

```
if (!isRequestSecure() && deployment.getSslRequired().isRequired(facade.getRequest().getRemoteAddr())) {
        log.error("Adapter requires SSL. Request: " + facade.getRequest().getURI());
        return challenge(403, OIDCAuthenticationError.Reason.SSL_REQUIRED, null);
    }
```

This is where the error comes from.
!isRequestSecure returns true because in my SimpleHttpFacade secure is set to false.

Comment: Did you find any solution or workaround to this?

Comment: Do you have the same issue? In my case the issue was because my company uses a customized header field instead of x-forwarded-for. So if yes, try to debug and check for the header fields.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, set `ssl-required: none`